# Let $ 0 \preceq A \preceq I$ can we relate $Tr( (I-A) B+A C)$ to $Tr(I-A)Tr(B)+Tr(A) Tr(C)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $ 0 \preceq A \preceq I$  and let $B$ and $C$ be two symmetric positive definite matrices.

Can we related
\begin{align}
{\rm Tr}( (I-A) B+A C)
\end{align}

to

\begin{align}
Tr(I-A)Tr(B)+Tr(A) Tr(C)
\end{align}

via some inequality?

Note, that in the case $A=aI$  for any $a\in [0,1]$ there is an equality.

**Edit:**
Note, from a very nice answer below we have:

\begin{align}
\lambda_{\min}(I-A){\rm Tr}(B)+\lambda_{\min}(A){\rm Tr}(C) \le {\rm Tr}( (I-A) B+A C) \le \lambda_{\max}(I-A){\rm Tr}(B)+\lambda_{\max}(A){\rm Tr}(C).
\end{align}

Comment: Just an observation, though it may not be useful to you. If $0\preceq A\preceq I$, then $0\preceq I-A\preceq I$. Therefore, if $B$ and $C$ are nonnegative matrices, $0\leq\operatorname{Tr}((I-A)B)\leq\operatorname{Tr}(B)$ and $0\leq\operatorname{Tr}(AC)\leq\operatorname{Tr}(C)$. It follows that in this case, $$0\leq\operatorname{Tr}((I-A)B+AC)\leq\operatorname{Tr}(B+C)$$ and $$0\leq\operatorname{Tr}(I-A)\operatorname{Tr}(B)+\operatorname{Tr}(A)(C)\leq\operatorname{Tr}(B+C)$$ (both quantities are nonnegative and bounded above by $\operatorname{Tr}(B+C)$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the function 
$$
\langle A,B \rangle = Tr(A^TB)
$$
defines an inner product over the real matrices.  As such, $\|A\|_2^2 = Tr(A^TA)$ is the norm induced by this inner product.  We have
$$
Tr((I-A)B + AC) = Tr((I-A)B) + Tr(AC) =\\
\langle I-A,B \rangle + \langle A,C \rangle \leq\\
\|I - A\|\,\|B\| + \|A\|\,\|C\| = \\
\sqrt{Tr[(I - A)^2]Tr(B^2) + Tr(A^2)Tr(C^2)}
$$
We can do a bit better using the inequality $|\langle A,B \rangle| \leq \sigma_1(A)\sum \sigma_i(B)$. In the symmetric positive semidefinite case, amounts to $|\langle A,B \rangle| \leq \rho(A) Tr(B)$, where $\rho$ denotes the spectral radius.  We now have
$$
\langle I-A,B \rangle + \langle A,C \rangle \leq\\
\rho(I - A)Tr(B) + \rho(A) Tr(C)
$$
This reduces to your result in the case that $A = aI$ for $a \in [0,1]$.

---

The reverse inequality works perfectly well for our purposes: note that $A \succeq \lambda_{min}(A)I$.  So, $C^{1/2}AC^{1/2} \succeq \lambda_{min}(A)C^{1/2}C^{1/2}$. We therefore have
$$
Tr((I-A)B + AC) = Tr((I-A)B) + Tr(AC) =\\
Tr(B^{1/2}(I-A)B^{1/2}) + Tr(C^{1/2}AC) \geq\\
Tr(\lambda_{min}(I - A)B^{1/2}B^{1/2}) + Tr( \lambda_{min}(A)C^{1/2}C^{1/2}) = \\
\lambda_{min}(I-A)Tr(B) + \lambda_{min}(A) Tr(C)
$$
in retrospect, a similar inequality could have worked in reverse.

Comment: I don't have a reference for these inequalities of the top of my head.  If someone could find such a reference, I would appreciate it.  I'm using the Hölder's inequalities for Schatten p-norms.

Comment: What is this second inequality called that you are using?  $ |<A ,B>| \le \sigma_1 \sum \sigma_i(B)$.

Comment: I don't know.  In Pedersen's "Analysis Now", it's lemma 3.4.10, and that's the infinite dimensional version.

Comment: See also proposition IV.2.4 from Bhatia's Matrix Analysis

Comment: @Boby I'm going to post my own question about that.

Comment: Ok. Send me a link.

Comment: @Boby [here it is](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2241879/81360).  Best of luck!

Comment: What is the definition of $|A|$?

Comment: @Boby $|A| = (A^TA)^{1/2}$.  When finding the singular values, $A^TA$ is the matrix with eigenvalues $\sigma_i^2$, so that $(A^TA)^{1/2}$ has eigenvalues $\sigma_i$.  If $A$ is symmetric positive semidefinite, then $|A| = A$. Note that $A^*$ is the more general equivalent of $A^T$.

Comment: Do you think there is a reverse inequality? For example, with a minimum Eigenvalue?

Comment: @Boby I would suspect that $Tr(AC) \geq \lambda_{min}(A)Tr(C)$.

Comment: Note that this would also be tight in the case of $A=a I$. Do you know of a possible reference for this inequality? Should we ask a new question?

Comment: @Boby see my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  One more question. Do you think inequalities with eigenvalues is the best we can hope for?

Comment: @Boby yes.  But inequalities of symmetric positive semidefinite matrices are nice, and have some very neat characterizations (e.g. via Rayleigh's theorem).

Comment: Final question.  Let $A,B,C$ be positive semi-definte. What is the inequality $Tr(AB)\le Tr(CB)$  where $A \preceq C$, called?

Comment: @Boby I have no idea.