# Lower bound nuclear norm of $A$ by $\mathrm{tr}(|A|)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, nuclear-norm

Let $A = (a_{ij}) \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be a square matrix. Let $\|A\|_\ast$ be the nuclear norm of $A$. Is the following true?

$$\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{ii}| \le \|A\|_\ast$$

Comment: Have you considered what happens if your matrix is symmetric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your statement is true.  In general, it can be shown that
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(BA) \leq \|A\|_*\|B\|_{\infty}
$$
Where $\|B\|_\infty$ is the spectral norm (i.e. the largest singular value) of $B$.  Your statement can be attained by taking $B$ to be a suitable diagonal matrix with $\pm 1$ on the diagonal.

See [my earlier question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2241879/81360) for more on the general inequality.