# An inequality about norms of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I encountered an inequality that I have no idea how to prove.

> $
> |\mathrm{Tr}(A^*B)| \leq ||A|| \cdot ||B||_1
> $, where $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$, and $||A||$ denotes the spectral (or operator) norm of $A$, and $||B||_1$ denotes the trace norm of $B$.

Maybe the first step we can do is to assume w.l.o.g. B is diagonal. But what to do then?

Comment: You are doing this for matrices? For completeness, please define the operator and trace norm as you know them (the definition you have).

Comment: You may want to see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241879/reference-for-trace-norm-inequality.