# Saturating an operator norm inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, normed-spaces, trace

I read the following statement:

> $\text{tr} [ A(B+C)] \leq \left\Vert B+C \right\Vert$. Since $B+C \geq 0$, one can always find $A$ s.t. the inequality is saturated.

Here, $A$ is a hermitian PSD matrix with $\text{tr}(A) = 1$, whereas $B,C \geq 0$ and also hermitian.

Regarding that, I have the following questions:

1. Is it obvious what operator norm they are using?
2. Why is $\text{tr} [ A(B+C)] \leq \left\Vert B+C \right\Vert$ true? Could I show that by saying $\text{tr} [ A(B+C)] \leq \left\Vert A \right\Vert \left\Vert B+C \right\Vert$, and as $\text{tr}(A) = 1 \Longrightarrow \left\Vert A \right\Vert \geq 1$, then the statement is true?
3. Why $B+C \geq 0$ must be true so that we can find $A$ that saturates the inequality?
4. How can I find such $A$ that saturates the bound? Is it related to the eigenvectors of $(B+C)$?

P.s.: I only know introductory linear algebra, so I'm sorry if these questions are obvious.

Comment: It seems from the context that the authors are referring to the [induced $2$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms). With that, it seems that the inequality holds as a consequence of [this general statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2241879/81360).

Comment: It also seems from the context that PSD matrices are, in this context, symmetric (or perhaps Hermitian) by definition. With that: if $\max_{\|x\| = 1}\|(B + C)x\|_2$ is attained with $x = v$, then taking $A = vv^T$ saturates the inequality.

Comment: The first comment solves the first question. For the second, you're correct, the matrices should be Hermitian. I've edited this into the question. For the answer on the saturation, is $v$ somehow related to any property of $B+C$, perhaps being an eigenvector of it? Thank you both.

Comment: Yes, $v$ is the eigenvector of $B+C$ associated with the maximal eigenvalue